# How to convert a 32 characters ip address to binary dotted decimal format?

Tags: python, ip-address

IP address `00000011100000001111111111111111` will be converted into dotted decimal format as: `3.128.255.255`. This is because the 1st 8 bits `00000011` will be converted to 3, the 2nd 8 bits `10000000` will be converted to 128, the 3rd 8 bits `11111111` will be converted to 255 and the last 8 bits `11111111` will be converted to 255.

How to write a function `ip_format()` that accepts an IP address in binary format and converts it into its dotted decimal format ?

Comment: "Write a function that...". YES SIR, at your disposal. Did you try anything at least?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module from the standard library:

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> def ip_format(ip):
...     return str(ipaddress.ip_address(int(ip, 2)))
...
>>> ip_format('00000011100000001111111111111111')
'3.128.255.255'
```

Otherwise, it's pretty easy to do it manually:

```
>>> def ip_format(ip):
...     return ".".join(map(str, int(ip, 2).to_bytes(4, "big")))
... 
>>> ip_format("00000011100000001111111111111111")
'3.128.255.255'
```

As far as the logic: you convert the binary string to an [integer](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#int), split that to individual bytes, convert those to strings, and join with `"."`.

Answer (score 1):

When you convert to `int` you can also specify a second argument that is the base (in this case `2` for binary). Then you can stride through your string 8 elements at a time, and lastly `join` with `'.'` characters

```
def ip_format(s):
    return '.'.join(str(int(s[i:i+8], 2)) for i in range(0, 32, 8))

>>> ip_format('00000011100000001111111111111111')
'3.128.255.255'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def ip_format(s): 
    return '.'.join(str(int(s[n * 8:(n + 1) * 8], 2)) for n in range(4))
```

Answer (score 1):

The string can be converted using standard Python libraries as follows:

```
import socket
import struct

ip_addr_binary = '00000011100000001111111111111111'  

print socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('>I', int(ip_addr_binary, 2)))
```

Which displays:

```
3.128.255.255
```

**How does it work?**

First convert the binary string into a corresponding integer using `int(x, 2)`. Next use [`struct.pack()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html?highlight=struct%20pack#struct.pack) to convert the number into a four character packed string. This can then be passed to [`socket.inet_ntoa(packed_ip)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html?highlight=socket%20inet_ntoa#socket.inet_ntoa) to convert it into a dot separated IP address.